# A tags have height but cannot be clicked

Tags: html, css, sass

I am having a problem where I have li tags wrapped by a tags and they both have a height but the links do not work.  I am confused as to why but here is a fiddle and my code.

```
<div id="homepageContentLeft">
        <ul>
            <a href="register.php"><li><span>Register Here</span></li></a>
            <a href="map.php"><li><span>Race Map</span></li></a>
            <a href="donate.php"><li><span>Donate</span></li></a>
            <a class="last" href="http://cff.org" target="_blank"><li class="last" ><img src="pictures/cfflogo1.png" alt="CFF" /></li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="slidesContainer">
        <div href="register.php" id="freeTShirt">Free T-shirt W/ Registration.</div>

        <div id="slides">
            <img src="pictures/pic1.jpg" alt="Race Beginning"/>
            <img src="pictures/pic2.jpg" alt="Race Beginning"/>
            <img src="pictures/pic3.jpg" alt="Race Beginning"/>
            <img src="pictures/pic4.jpg" alt="Race Beginning"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is my scss

```
#homepageContent {
    width: $pageWidth;
    margin: 1% auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

    #homepageContentLeft, #slides {
        float: left;
    }

    #homepageContentLeft {
        width: 30%;
        text-align: center;

        ul {
            list-style: none;
            margin-top: 0px;
            margin-right: 15px;
            margin-left: 0px;
            padding-left: 0px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;

            li:first-of-type {
                margin-top: 0px;
                //background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #A21945, #7A0026);
            }

            a {
                overflow: hidden;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: block;
                height: 85px;
                margin-bottom: 17px;


                li {
                    height: 85px;
                    vertical-align: middle;
                    font-size: 1.6em;
                    background-color: #0099ff;
                    color: white;
                    border-radius: 10px;
                    cursor: pointer;

                    span {
                        display: inline-block;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                        line-height: 85px;
                        width: 100%;
                    }

                    img {
                        display: block;
                        max-width: 100%;
                        height: 90%;
                        width: auto/9;
                        margin: 0 auto;
                    }
                }
            }


            li:hover {
                //background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #666666, #3d3d3d);
            }
            li.last, a.last {
                margin-bottom: 0px;
            }
        }
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/keS96/

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, you have to place the `<a>` inside of `<li>` not the other way around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem doesn't have anything to do with the height of your list items or links. The problem is that #slidesContainer is rendering over everything and blocking the click events. When you manually remove that node from the DOM the links work as expected.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this I added that container to my image slider recently and completely forgot to add the appropriate styling to it.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that contrary to other answers you recieved  it is valid to wrap block level elements in an a tag in HTML5. In many instances it is even preferable as a larger target area is created for touch devices.

http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/

Comment: Yes I completely agree.  That is why I do wrap my block level elements with my a tags.

Answer (score 3):

Took a quick glace at it and saw the you have a lot of questionable / wrong markup.

1. Put the links inside the li, not the li inside the links.

> ```
> <ul>
>   <li>
>     <a href="#" title="Link title" class="yourClass">Linktext</a>
>   </li>
> </ul>
> ```

1. Assign the style via the CSS, rather than assigning them inside the markup. The markup is for markup, the Stylingsheet is for styling.

To answer your question:
You assigned `float: left;` to the homepageContentLeft element. The slidesContainer does not have a float attribute and its width therefore "lays over" the Navigation. Assign a float element towards it and you'll fix your problem.

Comment: I never do put styling in my markup.  It's because I copy and pasted my html from the safari web inspect since my html is generated from a php script and I wanted to post just the html and not complicate it with including my entire script.  And in the safari web inspect I was changing the css so I could see its effect.

Answer (score 2):

Your "a" tags need to be inside of your "li" tags.